# Select rows where date is between [this] and [that]

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a table that has a column 'inspect_date'. This column contains dates in the format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS. I am trying to find the records that fall between April 2012 and September 2012. What can I put in my WHERE clause to be able to do this?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? Is it `datetime` or `char/varchar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from table
where inspect_date>= '04/01/2012 00:00:00.000'
and inspect_date< '10/01/2012 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: You probably want to include the rows where `inspect_date` is exactly `2012-04-01T00:00:00.000` so ...`inspect_date >= '2012-04-01T00:00:00.000 and inspect_date < '2012-10-01T00:00:00.000'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE inspect_date BETWEEN '2012-04-01' and '2012-09-30'
```

Comment: This will not return rows where `inspect_date` is for example `2012-09-30 09:00:00`.

Comment: It depends.  If inspect_date is a date type, then it will (and there will be no 2012-09-30 09:00:00 values in the database).  If inspect_date is a date time field, then it needs to be "BETWEEN '2012-04-01 00:00:00' and '2012-10-01 23:59:59'"

Comment: Yes it will work with a `date` but as you can see in the question it is not a `date` in this case. As for using `2012-10-01 23:59:59` you will still miss the values in the last second if the day. For instance `2012-10-01 23:59:59.997`

Comment: Ah, I missed the HH:MM:SS in the format.  Otherwise everything in the question indicated it was a date field.  Yes, the correct range should be to 2012-10-01 00:00:00.  (I got confused half way through my answer and mixed the next date with the end of the day.  Also wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ....WHERE 
inspect_date >= CAST('20120401' AS datetime) and
inspect_date <  CAST('20121001' AS datetime)

for year selection you can use

WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,inspect_date)=2012
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be flexible, try taking the date apart like this:

```
WHERE MONTH(inspect_date) > 3 AND YEAR(inspect_date)= 2011
OR MONTH(inspect_date) <= 5 AND YEAR(inspect_date)= 2012
```